# How to run the function when the specified url is entered reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, web3-react

I have two urls in my project. the first one: **http://localhost:3000/?/#chain=Matic**, and the other one: **http://localhost:3000/?/#chain=Bsc**. I want the function I created to run when entered with this url. How can I do that?

For example, when this **http://localhost:3000/?/#chain=Matic** address is entered, I want the relevant function to be loaded automatically after the page is loaded. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to amend the URL so that we're pulling from the get parameters. Then we can look for the variable when the page first loads and run logic depending on what the value is:

Here's a complete example: https://codesandbox.io/s/resolve-url-parameter-2odpc

Comment: Please do not post link only examples. Include the code in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm trying this method right now. i will get back to you as soon as possible

Comment: It was really a problem that I couldn't find a solution for for weeks. I have solved it because of you. Thank you very much. really.